# How to know what all compiler options used while building boost

Tags: boost

I have built boost in AIX. The build successful and the .so are created. But nm command shows no symbols on those libraries. I want to check what all options it used while compiling/linking the files. I am not finding any build logs.
Appreciate any pointers in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "-d+2" option to the build commands to show commands run as they run. Or you can also use the "-n" option to just show you the commands that it would run (without running them).

Comment: Thanks GrafikRobot, that helped.

Comment: @AnantaSwain .. Great. Can you accept the answer. For the benefit of others searching the same issue.